# Python Jupyter notebook- AWS RDS Mysql - Not able to connect

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am not able to  connect AWS RDS mysql using juypter notebook but i can connect via SQL workbench. Can you please throw some light on the error below

**Error Message** :-

**MSSQLDatabaseException: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist**

```
import pymssql
 
connection={
       'host': 'xxxxx.cuwwncrvmjhg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'username': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxxx',
    'db': 'mysql' 
 }


con=pymssql.connect(connection['host'],connection['username'],connection['password'],connection['db'])
```

Comment: Is the `db` really called `mysql` or is that a typo?

Comment: yes, it's mysql db not typo

Comment: `pymssql.connect` this and the error message indicates that you are using a library to connect to ms sql server, not to mysql. You need to use a library for mysql. Probably a typo, you wanted to use pymysql as opposed to pymssql.

Answer (score -1):

From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pymssql?view=sql-server-ver15), I see in pymssql.connect you need to specify key=value. Can you try:

```
import pymssql
 
connection={
    'host': 'xxxxx.cuwwncrvmjhg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'username': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'xxxx',
    'db': 'mysql' 
 }

con=pymssql.connect(server=connection['host'],user=connection['username'],password=connection['password'],database=connection['db'])
```

Comment: it's same error after update the code with server==connect***

Comment: @Raghav because of the typo in the library name as I already pointed it out.

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you i worked !! :) you made my day !!